# Activate GPRS connection on compact framework (c#)

Tags: c#, compact-framework, gprs

I'm developing an app in C# (.NET3.5 Compact Framework) and I need to connect to a sql server occasionally over GPRS. However the connection closes after some time of inactivity or if the PDA is placed on the craddle.

I'm looking for a way to check and re-enable the connection automatically from the app.

I've seen several pages on the web suggesting using the ConnectionManager, the Opennet.CF framework or an approach based on a XML doc. None provide a full example.

My latest test is based on the code below.

Could you help me with some suggestion or piece of code?

Many thanks in advance,

Filipe

```
public static void setCM_ProxyEntriesHTTP(Guid Guid)
    {
        try
        {
            remCM_ProxyEntries(getCM_ProxyEntriesAtual());
            string wWap = "<wap-provisioningdoc>" +
            "<characteristic type=\"CM_ProxyEntries\">" +
            "<characteristic type=\"HTTP-{" + Guid.ToString() + "}\">" +
            "<parm name=\"ExtraInfo\" value=\"\" />" +
            "<parm name=\"Override\" value=\"\" />" +
            "<parm name=\"Username\" value=\"\" />" +
            "<parm name=\"Enable\" value=\"1\" />" +
            "<parm name=\"Type\" value=\"0\" />" +
            "<parm name=\"DestId\" value=\"{436EF144-B4FB-4863-A041-8F905A62C572}\" />" +
            "<parm name=\"SrcId\" value=\"{" + Guid.ToString() + "}\" />" +
            "</characteristic>" +
            "</characteristic>" +
            "</wap-provisioningdoc>";
            ConfigWrapper.ProcessXml(wWap);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you josef! :)

I was able to check and connect using the following code:

```
 private static bool InternetAvailable2()
    {
        bool hasNet = false;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.bing.com");
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
            request.Proxy = null;
            //request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    hasNet = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"NetAvail2");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you do not need to care about the connection, as long as your request triggers the connection manager. So, before you do the SQL query or connection, do a http request on a known, reacable server. That http request will trigger the connection manager to open the connection. The connection manager will manage the connection.

If there is no data flowing for a longer period, connection manager (CM) will close the connection, except you configured an "always on" connection. 'Alwas on' can be configured with a wap provisioning xml file for the connection. A similar xml as you wrote (which is useless for your needs): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737329.aspx

The trick to trigger CM was needed in an app I wrote using ftp. I had to do a http request (to google.com) before I could open a ftp connection. FTP connection requests will NOT trigger CM, as sql requests will also not do.

So, in your code first do a http request and wait for or repeat until success, then issue your sql connection request.
-OR-
Configure an 'always on' connection (if you have a flat data rate contract with your internet provider).